# Xcode 9 crashed when run a block

Tags: ios, block, xcode9

If I install the app by Xcode 8  it works well,but when I install the app by Xcode 9 it  crashed, follow is my codes :

first is the header file

```
@interface EGCAction : NSObject

+ (instancetype )actionWithTitle:(NSString *)title
                         handler:(void(^)())handler
                           style:(EGCActionStyle)style;


@property (nonatomic, copy  )NSString       *title;
@property (nonatomic, assign)EGCActionStyle style;
@property (nonatomic, copy  )void(^handler)();

@end
```

I get a action array and run code as follow:

```
EGCAction *action = self.actions[index];

if (action.handler) {

    action.handler();
}
```

EGCAction is a class and  handler is a blcok prperty ,

[image]

Is there anyone can help me ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: May be the crash is happening inside the handler block. Can you just pass empty block as handler and check whether the crash is still there or not ?

Comment: thank you ,finally I found out it's a crying reason .....

Comment: What you found ? Could you please explain?

Comment: someone passed a arg to a no arg block..